# Codeigniter - PHP setting a single element of an session variable array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session, session-variables

Hi all I'm using CI and I have set an array using the CI built in methods as seen below:

```
$arrayBools = array();

for($y = 0; $y < 30; $y++){
    $arrayBools[$y] = false; 
}

$this->session->set_userdata('arrayBools', $arrayBools);
```

this works and sets the array in the session variable without an issue - however i am confused if I only want to change a single element in the array to true - could someone point me in the right direction - apologies if simple complete beginner to all of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's actually fairly simple: you just retrieve the array, modify the value, write it back to session

```
$arr = $this->session->userdata('arrayBools');
$arr[3] = false;
$this->session->set_userdata('arrayBools',$arr);
```

there ya go.

Comment: ok - I thought there may be a way without storing the array temporarily, Thankyou for the help - new it would be simple!

Answer (score 1):

I think CodeIgniter doesn't allow to do that.

You have no other choice that get all your array :

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('arrayBools');
```

then after editing your data to set all the array

```
$this->session->set_userdata('arrayBools',$data);
```

It's not possible to access only on item of an array set in session.